# React axios DELETE and POST adding to database but not updating state

Tags: reactjs, axios

When I delete an item, it is deleted from the database, but state is not updated until I refresh the page.

My understanding is that I don't want to update state directly, I want to make a copy of state, modify it, then overwrite the existing state, which should trigger a new render as it also removes the item from the database.

So I would think a spread operator would be ideal for this, but I can't seem to get it to re-render.

```
  class Projects extends Component {
  state = {
    projects: []
  };

  getProjects() {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5309/api/projects')
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ projects: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  deleteProject(event) {
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5309/api/projects/${event.target.value}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ projects: response.data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getProjects();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Projects">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
        <div className="projectContainer">
          {this.state.projects.map(project => {
            return (
              <div className="projects" key={project.id}>
                <Card>
                  <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>Name: {project.name}</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>
                      Project Description: {project.description}
                    </CardText>
                  </CardBody>
                  <Button color="secondary">Edit</Button>
                  <Button
                    color="danger"
                    type="submit"
                    value={project.id}
                    onClick={this.deleteProject}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </Button>
                </Card>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

Comment: Try to `console.log` the response in your delete function. Are you getting the response that you expect?

Comment: When I console.log response.data, I get a bunch of info such as status:200 , config, another data object, headers, etc. This is what I expected to see, I'm just not sure why it wouldn't update state as well.

Comment: In your constructor you set state.projects as an array. In your render method you are mapping an array obviously, but in your comment you state, "When I console.log response.data, I get a bunch of info such as status:200 , config, another data object, headers, etc.". That sounds like an object to me.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution ?